# Precedence group higher than closure

Tags: swift

I'm trying to define a custom operator in Swift with a precedence group higher than a closure.  In particular, I want to be able to write:

```
foo --> bar { 
    //... 
}
```

The `-->` operator returns a function that takes a closure of type `() -> Void` as it's sole parameter.

However, I have only been able to get

```
(foo --> bar) { 
    //... 
}
```

to work.  Is there an operator precedence that can make this work without parentheses?

Here's the precedence group for

```
precedencegroup LongArrowPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

infix operator --> : LongArrowPrecedence
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first set up a complete and verifiable example:

```
precedencegroup LongArrowPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

infix operator --> : LongArrowPrecedence

func -->(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> (() -> ()) -> () {
    return { print(lhs+rhs, terminator: ""); $0() }
}
```

As well as examples of the paranthesis-embraced valid calls using this operator, *immediately followed by a call to the closure which `-->` returns*.

```
let foo = 1
let bar = 2

// OK
(foo --> bar) { 
    print(" is the magic number")
} // 3 is the magic number

// OK
((-->)(foo, bar)) { 
    print(" is the magic number")
} // 3 is the magic number
```

This doesn't tell us much, but if we study the following failing cases

```
// ERROR: cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
foo --> bar { 
    print(" is the magic number")
} // 3 is the magic number

// ... equivalent to
// ERROR: cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
foo --> bar({ 
    print(" is the magic number")
}) // 3 is the magic number
```

We realize that the issue here is not *"precedence lower than a closure"*, but rather that a [function-call-argument-clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) (a set of parantheses following any postfix-expression­) will attempt a *call* to that postfix-expression­, as if the postfix-expression was a method/function/closure. If the postfix-expression is not callable, or if the call within the function-call-argument-clause does not match any overload of the callable, then the compiler will produce an error.

```
42()           // ERROR: cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
let foo = 42
foo()          // ERROR: cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

func bar() {}  // ERROR: argument passed to call that takes no arguments
bar(42)
```

Hence, the trailing closure supplied to the closure returned from `-->` is not relevant here: it's simply an argument to the returned closure, whereas the key issue is that Swift will apply a function-call-argument-clause to the postfix-expression­ which immediately precedes the clause. In you example, `bar` constitutes that postfix expression, and only if you wrap `foo --> bar` in parantheses will the combined wrapped expression constitute the postfix-expression­ onto which the following function-call-argument-clause is applied.

> **Postfix Expressions**
>
> Postfix expressions are formed by applying a postfix operator or other
>   postfix syntax to an expression. **Syntactically, every primary
>   expression is also a postfix expression.**
>
> **Primary Expressions**
>
> Primary expressions are the most basic kind of expression. They can be
>   used as expressions on their own, and they can be combined with other
>   tokens to make prefix expressions, binary expressions, and postfix
>   expressions.

You will not be able to circumvent this, as operator precedence is not applicable to the function-call-argument-clause; the latter (and its "precedence") is defined by the grammar of a function call expression.